# Different width of text split to various number of spans

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing a script, that should simulate typing text.
In brief I keep the text in `data.txt`. The element which text is appended to is `data.elem`. I wanted to have the text center aligned, so I used on the element `text-align:centetr;`. To avoid typing the text from the middle and then expand on both sides, I decided to split the text into two section:

```
.typed{
    visibility:hidden;
}
.untyped{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Here is the script fragment of the typing loop:

```
var the_data = '<span class="typed active">' + data.txt.substring(0, data.ch++) + '</span><span class="untyped">' + data.txt.substring(data.ch - 1, data.tot) + '</span>';
data.elem.html(the_data);
```

`data.ch` keeps the currently typed character and `data.tot` keeps the total length of text.

The problem is, that when i check the sum of typed and untyped spans width, it varies in some runs of loop (with some given characters i.e. comma) and an odd looking blink effect occurs (text changes it's position).

Does anybody have a hint, how to cope with that?

EDIT 1

Here is a screenshot from console. [image]

The number below each line, is sum of width of mentioned spans.

EDIT 2

I figured out what is the problem.
With font I am using (Termina, but checked few typical web fonts also):

```
<div>ZA</div>
```

has diferent width from:

```
<div><span>Z</span><span>A</span></div>
```

I have checked all styles and didn't find any property, that could change the width of whole div. Below is the list of computed properties of the span:

```
border-bottom-color:rgb(26, 2, 53);
border-bottom-style:none;
border-bottom-width:0px;
border-image-outset:0px;
border-image-repeat:stretch;
border-image-slice:100%;
border-image-source:none;
border-image-width:1;
border-left-color:rgb(26, 2, 53);
border-left-style:none;
border-left-width:0px;
border-right-color:rgb(26, 2, 53);
border-right-style:none;
border-right-width:0px;
border-top-color:rgb(26, 2, 53);
border-top-style:none;
border-top-width:0px;
box-sizing:border-box;
color:rgb(26, 2, 53);
display:inline;
font-family:termina, sans-serif;
font-size:60px;
font-stretch:normal;
font-style:normal;
font-variant-caps:normal;
font-variant-ligatures:normal;
font-variant-numeric:normal;
font-weight:800;
height:auto;
line-height:60px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
margin-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;
padding-top:0px;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align:baseline;
white-space:nowrap;
width:auto;
```

Mayby some ideas now? Mayby there is some css property I am missing?

Comment: You should post your entire code for us to have a look into it.

Comment: I would really like doing this, but it's a part of a pretty long sciprt. I will try to   craft a suitable fragment.

Comment: Why not? Actually after a while w think, that it's the the matter of js script. It might be a matter of different rendering characters in various combination of putting letters in spans.

Comment: Could this be the result of kerning rules being in effect? Have you tried a monospace font (which should not be affected by kerning)?

Comment: You could also test if setting `font-kerning: none;` in css would make a difference.

Comment: With font-kerning thing there can occur a browser compatibility problem.

As a workaround I put each letter in separate span and change their visibility